# How do I reduce the size of the app in windows phone 8.1 app?

Tags: windows, optimization, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have created my first windows phone app. Basically this is Tambola game. My problem is that the size of the app is around 27 Mbs. The app size on other platforms is much smaller compared to Windows Phone.

Please suggest any way to reduce the size. I have already reduced the size of the image and audio files.

Here is the link for the app: http://bit.ly/1MXy9uj

Also please suggest me what could be even better. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use .png with empty background images, that will reduce the size of the app. Particularly I think the weight is because image resources

Comment: I have used the same where ever is necessary. Can we use vector images so that we can adjust the sizes according to different screen size?

Comment: Windows phone uses 3 sizes for pictures. Exceeds my knowledge because the designer gives the 3 sizes. You should read the guides design windows phone from MSDN. Greetings!